# Angular - Route only on condition (Based on localStorage)

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application using basic Routing module. The below shows my defined routes:

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];
...
```

Now I want to protect my dashboard route. I want to route only when I have a `localStorage` object named `token`. How can I do it?

```
var local = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
```

Something like:

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', checkLogin, component: DashboardComponent }
];
...
function checkLogin(){
    // do the logic
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Angular Route Guards. Like this:

```js
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router'; 

class DashBoardGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    if (// your condition)  {
      return true; // all fine
    } else {//maybe redirect somwhere}
  }
  
}

// in your routes
...
{path: 'dashboard', canActivate: {[DashBoardGuard]}
```

Read more about guards [here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Comment: How can I do it for multiple routes? Lets say I want to protect `/dashboard` as well as `/profile`. Do I need to write a function for each and every route then? How can I make it more generic?

Comment: If the logic for protecting `/dashboard` and `/profile` is different, then yes, obviously you'll have to write a Guard for each. But if it's the same, you can just reuse the existing guard, or if a guard refers to certain lazy loaded modules, you can place a guard on the parent to prevent lazy loading

Comment: It is not different logic but the same. Can you elaborate your above example as to how to handle for both routes with single logic? I am new to angular not quite clear on things.

Comment: If the logic is entirely the same for both routes you just have to place `canActivate: {[DashBoardGuard]}` on both of them. You can rename the guard to resemble something more generic, rather than something referring to `DashBoardComponent`, maybe `TokenGuard`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a route guard that implements the CanActivate interface:
https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

The canActivate method can return a boolean if it's supposed to be checked synchronously or promise/observable if it's async. Anyway, in your case, you're just checking the localStorage so you simply return true or false based on the token.